# No me funciona background-position: center center;

Tags: background

tengo una imagen, y quiero centrarla tanto horizontal como verticalmente, no me funciona, y si la quiero colocar a la derecha y abajo, sale es arriba:

```
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1635398517284-2f3c7fef7fee?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1172&q=80);
    background-position: center center;
}
```

El resultado, es como se ve en la captura[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, agrega el html necesario para eso, junto con su CSS completo. Ahora mismo, no se donde estas aplicando las reglas, si al body, un div, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Te ha faltado agregar un `background-attachment`
Con esta propiedad, la imagen no se desplazará con el contenido. Que es lo que hace que si la pones en el `right bottom`, la termines viendo arriba a la derecha.

```css
body{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://i.gyazo.com/005a51f3345762185550aec273318c8e.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: Listo, voy a revisarlo, muchísimas gracias !!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a meterle un hegiht || min-height

https://codepen.io/elazafran/pen/GRvvKMx

Comment: Listo, voy a revisarlo, muchísimas gracias !!!!!!!

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.